# Getting emoticons from Twitter API in PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to find a way to either

- Remove
- Replace with images
- Replace with fonts

The emoticons I am getting back from the Twitter API.

At present, a Tweet like this:

```
[text] => RT @50SombrasQuotes: Emoticons que nos ayudan a resumir a nuestros amores literarios. #FSOG #FiftyShades #SoyLectora #AyC  http://t.co/w7…
```

Is coming back with the two rectangles . [If you visit the tweet however](https://twitter.com/50SombrasQuotes/status/508790432500039682), they are beings displayed more similarly to the following:

```
<img class="twitter-emoji" src="https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/1f60d.png" draggable="false" alt="" title="Smiling face with heart-shaped eyes" aria-label="Emoji: Smiling face with heart-shaped eyes">
```

Can anyone shed any light on how to go about this? Thanks.

*Full twitter response:*

```
Array(
[metadata] => Array
    (
        [iso_language_code] => es
        [result_type] => recent
    )

[created_at] => Tue Sep 09 04:30:29 +0000 2014
[id] => 509197123100110850
[id_str] => 509197123100110850
[text] => RT @50SombrasQuotes: Emoticons que nos ayudan a resumir a nuestros amores literarios. #FSOG #FiftyShades #SoyLectora #AyC  http://t.co/w7…
[source] => Twitter for iPhone
[truncated] => 
[in_reply_to_status_id] => 
[in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
[in_reply_to_user_id] => 
[in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
[in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
[user] => Array
    (
        [id] => 358901144
        [id_str] => 358901144
        [name] => Karo✌
        [screen_name] => imkarolina_
        [location] => Monterrey, algún día Madrid✌
        [description] => Quiero tener muchos gatos obesos con @Rubiu5 ❤❤☺
        [url] => 
        [entities] => Array
            (
                [description] => Array
                    (
                        [urls] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [protected] => 
        [followers_count] => 688
        [friends_count] => 1279
        [listed_count] => 0
        [created_at] => Sat Aug 20 17:59:43 +0000 2011
        [favourites_count] => 1532
        [utc_offset] => -18000
        [time_zone] => Central Time (US & Canada)
        [geo_enabled] => 
        [verified] => 
        [statuses_count] => 8028
        [lang] => es
        [contributors_enabled] => 
        [is_translator] => 
        [is_translation_enabled] => 
        [profile_background_color] => FF6699
        [profile_background_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/826326887/16720799c9ebf06a7b2e71d8432ce42a.jpeg
        [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/826326887/16720799c9ebf06a7b2e71d8432ce42a.jpeg
        [profile_background_tile] => 1
        [profile_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/498321237073223680/I-jY0wef_normal.jpeg
        [profile_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/498321237073223680/I-jY0wef_normal.jpeg
        [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/358901144/1407644138
        [profile_link_color] => 920DB3
        [profile_sidebar_border_color] => FFFFFF
        [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => E5507E
        [profile_text_color] => 362720
        [profile_use_background_image] => 1
        [default_profile] => 
        [default_profile_image] => 
        [following] => 
        [follow_request_sent] => 
        [notifications] => 
    )

[geo] => 
[coordinates] => 
[place] => 
[contributors] => 
[retweeted_status] => Array
    (
        [metadata] => Array
            (
                [iso_language_code] => es
                [result_type] => recent
            )

        [created_at] => Mon Sep 08 01:34:26 +0000 2014
        [id] => 508790432500039682
        [id_str] => 508790432500039682
        [text] => Emoticons que nos ayudan a resumir a nuestros amores literarios. #FSOG #FiftyShades #SoyLectora #AyC  http://t.co/w7hIAs9rn3
        [source] => Twitter Web Client
        [truncated] => 
        [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
        [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
        [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
        [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
        [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
        [user] => Array
            (
                [id] => 865803847
                [id_str] => 865803847
                [name] => 50 Sombras de Grey
                [screen_name] => 50SombrasQuotes
                [location] => 
                [description] => |http://t.co/fiolusxYDN|

                    50 Sombras de Grey, frases, noticias y más.  {Fansite} No estamos afiliados con E.L. James, Grijalbo ó Universal Pictures.
                [url] => http://t.co/Yx99Hv5ma4
                [entities] => Array
                    (
                        [url] => Array
                            (
                                [urls] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [url] => http://t.co/Yx99Hv5ma4
                                                [expanded_url] => http://50sombrasgrey.tumblr.com/
                                                [display_url] => 50sombrasgrey.tumblr.com
                                                [indices] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => 0
                                                        [1] => 22
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [description] => Array
                            (
                                [urls] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [url] => http://t.co/fiolusxYDN
                                                [expanded_url] => http://www.facebook.com/50SombrasQuotes
                                                [display_url] => facebook.com/50SombrasQuotes
                                                [indices] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => 1
                                                        [1] => 23
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [protected] => 
                [followers_count] => 65500
                [friends_count] => 16
                [listed_count] => 79
                [created_at] => Sun Oct 07 05:15:31 +0000 2012
                [favourites_count] => 1467
                [utc_offset] => -14400
                [time_zone] => Eastern Time (US & Canada)
                [geo_enabled] => 
                [verified] => 
                [statuses_count] => 2527
                [lang] => es
                [contributors_enabled] => 
                [is_translator] => 
                [is_translation_enabled] => 
                [profile_background_color] => 131516
                [profile_background_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000115922355/b751e65cb743e2f9457503a79bf5bc70.png
                [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000115922355/b751e65cb743e2f9457503a79bf5bc70.png
                [profile_background_tile] => 1
                [profile_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2711247341/f8769a5f5b3a97c50f0fc4b44537674b_normal.jpeg
                [profile_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2711247341/f8769a5f5b3a97c50f0fc4b44537674b_normal.jpeg
                [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/865803847/1406063465
                [profile_link_color] => 009999
                [profile_sidebar_border_color] => FFFFFF
                [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6
                [profile_text_color] => 333333
                [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                [default_profile] => 
                [default_profile_image] => 
                [following] => 
                [follow_request_sent] => 
                [notifications] => 
            )

        [geo] => 
        [coordinates] => 
        [place] => 
        [contributors] => 
        [retweet_count] => 57
        [favorite_count] => 72
        [entities] => Array
            (
                [hashtags] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [text] => FSOG
                                [indices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 65
                                        [1] => 70
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [text] => FiftyShades
                                [indices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 71
                                        [1] => 83
                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [text] => SoyLectora
                                [indices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 84
                                        [1] => 95
                                    )

                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [text] => AyC
                                [indices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 96
                                        [1] => 100
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [symbols] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [urls] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [user_mentions] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [media] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 508790429358518273
                                [id_str] => 508790429358518273
                                [indices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 104
                                        [1] => 126
                                    )

                                [media_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bw-WMycIcAELV1H.jpg
                                [media_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bw-WMycIcAELV1H.jpg
                                [url] => http://t.co/w7hIAs9rn3
                                [display_url] => pic.twitter.com/w7hIAs9rn3
                                [expanded_url] => http://twitter.com/50SombrasQuotes/status/508790432500039682/photo/1
                                [type] => photo
                                [sizes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [medium] => Array
                                            (
                                                [w] => 369
                                                [h] => 221
                                                [resize] => fit
                                            )

                                        [thumb] => Array
                                            (
                                                [w] => 150
                                                [h] => 150
                                                [resize] => crop
                                            )

                                        [small] => Array
                                            (
                                                [w] => 340
                                                [h] => 204
                                                [resize] => fit
                                            )

                                        [large] => Array
                                            (
                                                [w] => 369
                                                [h] => 221
                                                [resize] => fit
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [favorited] => 
        [retweeted] => 
        [possibly_sensitive] => 
        [lang] => es
    )

[retweet_count] => 57
[favorite_count] => 0
[entities] => Array
    (
        [hashtags] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => FSOG
                        [indices] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 86
                                [1] => 91
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => FiftyShades
                        [indices] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 92
                                [1] => 104
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => SoyLectora
                        [indices] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 105
                                [1] => 116
                            )

                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => AyC
                        [indices] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 117
                                [1] => 121
                            )

                    )

            )

        [symbols] => Array
            (
            )

        [urls] => Array
            (
            )

        [user_mentions] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [screen_name] => 50SombrasQuotes
                        [name] => 50 Sombras de Grey
                        [id] => 865803847
                        [id_str] => 865803847
                        [indices] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 3
                                [1] => 19
                            )

                    )

            )

        [media] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 508790429358518273
                        [id_str] => 508790429358518273
                        [indices] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 139
                                [1] => 140
                            )

                        [media_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bw-WMycIcAELV1H.jpg
                        [media_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bw-WMycIcAELV1H.jpg
                        [url] => http://t.co/w7hIAs9rn3
                        [display_url] => pic.twitter.com/w7hIAs9rn3
                        [expanded_url] => http://twitter.com/50SombrasQuotes/status/508790432500039682/photo/1
                        [type] => photo
                        [sizes] => Array
                            (
                                [medium] => Array
                                    (
                                        [w] => 369
                                        [h] => 221
                                        [resize] => fit
                                    )

                                [thumb] => Array
                                    (
                                        [w] => 150
                                        [h] => 150
                                        [resize] => crop
                                    )

                                [small] => Array
                                    (
                                        [w] => 340
                                        [h] => 204
                                        [resize] => fit
                                    )

                                [large] => Array
                                    (
                                        [w] => 369
                                        [h] => 221
                                        [resize] => fit
                                    )

                            )

                        [source_status_id] => 508790432500039682
                        [source_status_id_str] => 508790432500039682
                    )

            )

    )

[favorited] => 
[retweeted] => 
[possibly_sensitive] => 
[lang] => es
)
```

Comment: I was curious about this, so I went and had a look. Seems like most everything I found implemented some form of [this extension on git](https://github.com/iamcal/php-emoji). There's a [Twitter Tracker plugin for Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/twitter-tracker/) that had an article about it. I downloaded the plugin and checked the source code, and it does almost the exact same, just examining the string and serving the proper emoji. There is a css file that is required to be included, so a bit more overhead. Seem's pretty straight forward, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'd actually already found that, I was just wondering if its the cleanest solution. Its interesting the Twitter API itself doesn't offer any examples with emoticons. I'll try and implement it now, thanks!

Comment: Emoji are encoded as unicode characters, if they are not displaying properly in a particular program or on a particular machine, it is probably because of the particular program you are using is not using up-to-date criteria to determine whether a given unicode code point is printable or assigned to a character. If you display the same text elsewhere (cat in bash maybe) it should display correctly. Also make sure you have saved the strings with utf8 encoding.